# Session created and deleted with a delay : Android webView

Tags: yii2, android-webview

My website uses `Yii2` as a framework, there I used `“Dektrium user”` module to implement registration and auth. In config, I  set `autologin` property to `“true”`

When I registered on my site (opened via `webView`), the session is opened, I stay `logged in`, and it’s ok, but when I close my app and open it again - I see `login form` and I need to enter my registration data again. But, If I wait (about 30 sec - 1 minute) and then close the app - session will be saved and I can open the app again and use without entering my `login` and pass.

The same situation related with `log out`: if I click to `“log out”` and quite quickly close `webView` app, and then open again - I am still `logged in`.

The most strange part is that in `iPhone` `webView` all working fine. Of course, I tried to reproduce this bug via browser, without `webView` - and they're all working fine too.

Maybe anyone has some ideas, why `webView` can `“freeze”` session with some delay?

Comment: you are using `dektrium-user` what value are you using for the `Yii::$app->user->login()` in the `LoginForm` as it uses the module `rememberFor` property to be passed if set, it defaults to 2 weeks. i just removed an answer that i posted here can you confirm these things

Answer (score 0):

## `About login()`

> If `$enableSession` is true:
>
> - the identity information will be stored in the session and be available in
>     the next requests
> - in case of `$duration == 0`: as long as the session
>     remains active or till the user closes the browser
> - in case of `$duration > 0`: as long as the session remains active or as long ? as the
>     cookie remains valid by it's `$duration` in seconds when
>     `$enableAutoLogin` is set `true`.

You need to use the second parameter for the `Yii::$app->user->login();` which defines what number of seconds that the user can remain in logged-in status, defaults to `0`.

```
//keep the cookie duration valid for 120 seconds or 2 minutes
Yii::$app->user->login($user,120);
```

As you have set the `$enableAutoLogin` to `true` so this parameter is not being ignored and the default value of `0` is used and the session is cleared as soon as you close the app. See the [**`DOCS`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-user#login()-detail) for more details.

For `Dektrium-user` you are using the value is set in the module's `LoginForm` model on top it uses the `rememberMe` property

```
Yii::$app->getUser()->login($this->user, $this->rememberMe ? $this->module->rememberFor : 0);
```

which defaults to `false` and works with the `checkbox` on the login form for this property to be set to true

```
 /** @var string Whether to remember the user */
    public $rememberMe = false;
```

So that means if you are not using the `rememberMe` checkbox on the login form to login the session and cookie will remain valid for `0` seconds as soon logged out or window closed.

You can set the `else` part value from `0` to any custom like `60` for 1 minute

```
Yii::$app->getUser()->login($this->user, $this->rememberMe ? $this->module->rememberFor : 60);
```

OR (I don't like this part thou)

You can set `public $rememberMe=true;` by default so that it always passes the default value of two weeks to be remembered if not logged out.
You can configure a custom value in the module settings in the config under `modules` too if you don't want the default `rememberFor` value (2 weeks).

```
'components'=>[
     'user'=>[
         'rememberFor'=>3000,
```

Comment: Muhammad, thank you for your so full response, but you describe some general settings, like a  'rememberFor'=>3000.
I already implemented this, and it's working fine in all popular browsers, excluding on `Android webView`.


Bug observed only there.